# Spigot 1.12 Event Player Ride Pig

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

We are making a Player ride a Pig in a minigame, and setting the velocity of that pig to make the player move. However, when a player is riding a pig, the PlayerMoveEvent is no longer triggered so we can not detect the movement of the player. This I'm sure worked back in 1.8.

Question is, what event will be fired in 1.12 or is there a way we can modify what we're doing to make this work?

Comment: Maybe you can verify a EntityMoveEvent and check if there's a player riding it?

Comment: You would verify the Pig's movement, which has the player riding it as a Vehicle

Comment: @Kerooker I don't believe there is an EntityMoveEvent anymore? I think that's what was used prior to 1.9 but I believe that's since been changed to PlayerMoveEvent and Entities can no longer be tracked without NMS Data which I struggle to understand at the best of times so I would like to stay away from that if possible.

Comment: We have the plugin coded for 1.8, but we were trying to update to 1.12 and this has since created this issue.

Comment: What about a VehicleMoveEvent?

Comment: You could also use [BKCommonsLib](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/bkcommonlib.39590/)

Answer (score 0):

You are actually uniquely poised to solve this using a timer and yaw. If you constantly update the pig's location in micromovements in the direction of the player's yaw you will have your desired effect. This is actually made easier through Bukkit library's vector system. If you use #getLocation().getDirection() on a Player object you will be returned a vector that will easily be transferable into pig velocity.